# Should a lookup table (LUT) be a property of an image or not (in Architectue)

Tags: java, c#, c++, graphics, architecture

So this is more about architecture.
We're facing the data design question whether we should add the to be used look up table to our image class (which contains the actual raw data) or not.

Arguments for it may be that palettes usually are part of usual image classes in libraries. See for example `BitmapSource`.

Arguments against it may be that a LUT is a modification like scale on an image representation (eg. a viewer). So it is going to be a viewer property. But not necessarily.

So what is your opinion on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data contained in the image makes sense only when associated with the LUT, then I would include the LUT in the image.

If the LUT is just used for presentation purposes of some sort of data that make sense also when not associated with a LUT, then I would put the LUT outside of the image class.

For instance:

- for a GIF image I would put the LUT in the class, because the raw data doesn't make sense if not associated with the correct colors.
- for an image containing some B/W data, or where each pixel represents the "people per square mile" or other data that can stand on its own, then I would put the LUT outside

If you need the LUT both for converting raw data to meaningful data (e.g. from GIF palette to RGB) and also for presentation (e.g. to highlight some structures in a BW image) then the LUT should have its own class, but the image should link to the LUT needed to derive meaningful data from the raw one.

For instance, the DICOM standard (medical imaging) allows for both presentation LUT and "transformation" (invented term, I don't remember the correct one) LUT: you can have plenty of presentation LUTs that highlight different part of an image, but only one transformation LUT that is used to derive meaningful data from RAW data whose meaning is known only by the producer of the medical device.
So the image has ONE link to the transformation LUT, but is not aware of the presentation ones.

Comment: Good answer. Received a third way where one share of the LUTs is part of the image and others is presentation. I recon this is exactly my confusion about this topic. And BTW actually it is DICOM ;-)